# Synchronising events between microservices using Kafka and MongoDb connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, microservices, apache-kafka-connect

I'm experimenting with microservices architecture. I have `UserService` and `ShoppingService`.
In `UserService` I'm using MongoDb. When I'm creating new user in `UserService` I want to sync basic user info to `ShoppingService`. In `UserService` I'm using something like event sourcing. When I'm creating new `User`, I first create the `UserCreatedEvent` and then I apply the event onto domain `User` object. So in the end I get the domain `User` object that has current state and list of events containing one `UserCreatedEvent`.

I wonder if I should persist the `Events` collection as a nested property of `User` document or in separate `UserEvents` collection. I was planning to use Kafka Connect to synchronize the events from `UserService` to `ShoppingService`.

If I decide to persist the events inside the `User` document then I don't need transaction that I would use to save event to separate `UserEvents` collection but I can't setup the Kafka connector to track changes in the nested property only.

If I decide to persist events in separate `UserEvents` collection I need to wrap in transaction changes to `User` and `UserEvents`. But saving events to separate collection makes setting up Kafka connector very easy because I track only inserts and I don't need to track updates of nested `UserEvents` array in `User` document.

I think I will go with the second option for sake of simplicity but maybe I've missed something. Is it good idea to implement it like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would generally advise the second approach.  Note that you can also eliminate the need for a transaction by observing that `User` is just a snapshot based on the `UserEvents` up to some point in the stream and thus doesn't have to be immediately updated.

With this, your read operation for `User` can be: select a user from `User` (the latest snapshot), which includes a version/sequence number saying that it's as-of some event; then select the events with later sequence numbers and apply those events to the user.  If there's some querier which wants a faster response and can tolerate getting something stale, a different endpoint (or an option in the query) can bypass the event replay.

You can then have some asynchronous process which subscribes to the stream of user events and updates `User` based on those events.